# VC dimension of rectangles in 2D space

Tags: machine-learning, classification, vc-dimension

I understand that the VC dimension of axis-aligned rectangles is 4 because there exists a set of 4 points that can be shattered by a rectangle and any set of 5 points cannot be shattered by a rectangle.

But what happens if we remove the constraint that they need to be axis aligned.

In short, what is VC dimension of rectangles in 2D with no constraints w.r.t alignment?